# persistent store with apache ignite xml configuration

Tags: configuration-files, ignite, persistent-storage

I want to use apache ignite as a cache for my database and I use [persitent store](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/persistent-store) for this.
My database is Cassandra and for configuration I use this [wiki](https://github.com/irudyak/ignite/wiki/Examples).

With this initialization I run ignite in windows:

> ignite.bat cassandra-ignite-config.xml

cassandra-ignite-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Cassandra connection settings -->
    <import resource="connection-settings.xml" />

    <!-- Persistence settings for 'cache1' -->
    <bean id="cache1_persistence_settings" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.utils.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings">
        <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource" value="persistence-settings-1.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Persistence settings for 'cache2' -->
    <bean id="cache2_persistence_settings" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.utils.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings">
        <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource" value="classpath:org/apache/ignite/tests/persistence/blob/persistence-settings-3.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Ignite configuration -->
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <!-- Configuring persistence for "cache1" cache -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="cache1"/>
                    <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                            <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraAdminDataSource"/>
                            <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache1_persistence_settings"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                <!-- Configuring persistence for "cache2" cache -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="cache2"/>
                    <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                    <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                            <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraAdminDataSource"/>
                            <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache2_persistence_settings"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

connection-setting.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="cassandraAdminCredentials" class="org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraAdminCredentials"/>

    <bean id="loadBalancingPolicy" class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RoundRobinPolicy"/>

    <bean id="contactPoints" class="org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraHelper" factory-method="getContactPointsArray"/>

    <bean id="cassandraAdminDataSource" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.utils.datasource.DataSource">
        <property name="credentials" ref="cassandraAdminCredentials"/>
        <property name="contactPoints" ref="contactPoints"/>
        <property name="readConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="writeConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="loadBalancingPolicy" ref="loadBalancingPolicy"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

persistence-setting-1.xml:

```
<persistence keyspace="test1" table="my_table">
    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.Integer" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="my_key"/>
    <valuePersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" />
</persistence>
```

but I have this error:

> class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring
>   XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring
>   configuration are present at CLASSPATH)
>   [springUrl=file:~/config/cassandra-ignite-config.xml]
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:927)
>           at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:350)
>           at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:302)
>   Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to
>   instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used
>   in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH)
>   [springUrl=file:~/config/cassandra-ignite-config.xml]
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:387)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:638)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:839)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:748)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:618)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:588)
>           at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
>           ... 1 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraAdminCredentials]
>   for bean with name 'cassandraAdminCredentials' defined in URL
>   [file:~/config/connection-settings.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.Cassan
>   draAdminCredentials
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1325)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:623)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1394)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:957)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:705)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:381)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.tests.utils.CassandraAdminCredentials
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:246)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1346)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1317)
>           ... 17 more Failed to start grid: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring
>   configuration are present at CLASSPATH)
>   [springUrl=~/config/cassandra-ignite-config.xml] 
>   Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath. Press any key to continue . . .

it seems there is something missed but I don't understand it.

**Update:**

I use [base-concepts](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/base-concepts) and example number 4 of the [examples](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/examples).
but know I have the serialization problem for pojo example.

error:

```
[16:24:11,033][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#2%null%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to unmarshal discovery data for component: 1
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5e9f23b4
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:128)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:142)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9779)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.onExchange(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1716)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processNodeAddedMessage(ServerImpl.java:4216)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2538)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2362)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerAdapter.body(ServerImpl.java:6436)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2445)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3543390829981374356, local class serialVersionUID = 4263059111698998196
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:120)
    ... 11 more
```

**Update 2:**

my pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>aryahamrah.ds</groupId>
        <artifactId>igniteHello</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
            </dependency>




            <!--for cassandra -->

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
                <version>3.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core &ndash;&gt;-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.collections/google-collections -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-cassandra-store &ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--<dependency>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>ignite-cassandra-store</artifactId>-->
                <!--<version>1.8.0</version>-->
            <!--</dependency>-->

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-cassandra -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-cassandra</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.22</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.22</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

connection-setting.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="loadBalancingPolicy" class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.TokenAwarePolicy">
        <constructor-arg type="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.LoadBalancingPolicy">
            <bean class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RoundRobinPolicy"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cassandraAdminDataSource" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.datasource.DataSource">
        <property name="readConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="writeConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="loadBalancingPolicy" ref="loadBalancingPolicy"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cassandraRegularDataSource" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.datasource.DataSource">
        <property name="readConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="writeConsistency" value="ONE"/>
        <property name="loadBalancingPolicy" ref="loadBalancingPolicy"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Update 3:**

when I put to the cache nothing happens but when I want to get,  I have these errors:

```
[15:16:16,008][SEVERE][pub-#53%null%][GridTaskWorker] Failed to obtain remote job result policy for result from ComputeTask.result(..) method (will fail the whole task): GridJobResultImpl [job=C4V2 [r=HelloWorld$$Lambda$8/98974893@5977d9a0], sib=GridJobSiblingImpl [sesId=c92fc496951-0257bdb2-3066-4861-8c60-47febea167d5, jobId=d92fc496951-0257bdb2-3066-4861-8c60-47febea167d5, nodeId=f2c7d14b-401f-4aea-a9af-50deeb7cb85e, isJobDone=false], jobCtx=GridJobContextImpl [jobId=d92fc496951-0257bdb2-3066-4861-8c60-47febea167d5, timeoutObj=null, attrs={}], node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=f2c7d14b-401f-4aea-a9af-50deeb7cb85e, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.113], sockAddrs=[LT-88273/169.254.247.78:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.1.113:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1483530374957, loc=false, ver=1.8.0#20161205-sha1:9ca40dbe, isClient=false], ex=class o.a.i.IgniteException: HelloWorld, hasRes=true, isCancelled=false, isOccupied=true]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Remote job threw user exception (override or implement ComputeTask.result(..) method if you would like to have automatic failover for this exception).
    at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeTaskAdapter.result(ComputeTaskAdapter.java:101)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$5.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1030)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$5.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1023)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6596)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.result(GridTaskWorker.java:1023)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:841)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.processJobExecuteResponse(GridTaskProcessor.java:996)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.finishJob(GridJobWorker.java:843)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.finishJob(GridJobWorker.java:745)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:608)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:479)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: HelloWorld
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.initialize(GridJobWorker.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1894)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1082)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1700(GridIoManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:673)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: HelloWorld
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9785)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.initialize(GridJobWorker.java:428)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: HelloWorld
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:689)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadClass(BinaryUtils.java:1480)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadClass(BinaryUtils.java:1418)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readClass(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:370)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.readFixedType(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:828)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:639)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:829)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1498)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1450)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1634)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readObject(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C4V2.readBinary(GridClosureProcessor.java:2230)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:819)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1498)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1450)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:298)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:100)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9779)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8393)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextAdapter.getClass(MarshallerContextAdapter.java:185)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:680)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using ignite as a cache for cassandra database, at first, it's better to read these documentations:

- [Ignite With Apache Cassandra](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/ignite-with-apache-cassandra)
- [BaseConcepts](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/base-concepts)
- [Examples](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/examples)

Now, you can run ignite with any nodes you want, but you must consider two things:

1. first, you must run ignite with the configured xml for cassandra
   connection
2. second, you must add dependent jar files for running
   ignite-cassandra

For simple cassandra configuration, you can use [this](https://gitlab.com/babak/ignite-cassandra/raw/master/cassandra/cassandra.xml) and for generate dependency jar files for your code, you can use `maven-dependency-plugin` with `copy-dependency` goal to generate jar files in the dependency folder of your target files.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After compiling your code, you can add dependency folder to the path of ignite libs or add to the `USER_LIBS` path. Now, you need to implement your java code. For this, I use the [class PersonId](https://gitlab.com/babak/ignite-cassandra/raw/master/src/main/java/cassandra/PersonId.java) and configure it with [this xml](https://gitlab.com/babak/ignite-cassandra/raw/master/src/main/resources/org/datascience/persistence-setting.xml). [hint: you need to add your project jar file to the ignite path.]

Now, you can run your ignite and after that run [your code](https://gitlab.com/babak/ignite-cassandra/raw/master/src/main/java/HelloWorld.java) and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

For using Cassandra as a persistent store you don't need CassandraAdminCredentials cause it's just used for tests. Example configuration you can look at  https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/ignite-with-apache-cassandra and https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/base-concepts

CassandraAdminCredentials class is only available in Ignite unit tests sources. If you want to use it you should build Ignite from source code. Such way, it will create ignite-cassandra-tests-${project.version}.zip where jar may find jar file containing all the test classes.

Comment: For more detail about building ignite-cassandra-tests-${project.version}.zip look at user-list [http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Cassandra-basic-setup-td9154.html](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com)

Comment: tnx for your help. I use [base-concepts](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/base-concepts) and example number 4 of the [examples](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/examples).
but know I have the serialization problem for pojo example

Comment: Make sure that all Ignite nodes start on the same JVM version and Ignite instances contains ignite-cassandra*.jar in classpath.

Comment: my problem was with ignite-cassandra jar file. I used ignite-cassandra-store version 1.8. 
With using ignite-cassandra versin 1.7, I don't have any errors but the keyspace and table doesn't created in the cassandra.

Comment: @Divuneh when do you update cache (put/remove) what happened?

Comment: You class `Person` extends `Externalizable` interface. In this case you should added this class in classpath for all nodes or just doesn't extend `Externalizable` for this class.

Comment: tnx a lot. after deleting Externalizable I run the program and it goes well( the object put & get), but   the problem still exists. there is no new keyspace and table in the cassandra.
The other problem is when I run another node and then run this node(my java code), other node has errors:
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Spring bean with provided name doesn't exist , beanName=cassandraAdminDataSource]

Comment: @Divuneh Keyspace and table will be create after first put/get operation on cache with enabled CassandraStore. Also you need to start other nodes with the same xml config (that your start your java code).

Comment: yes, I do that. My problem was with ignite-cassandra version. With replacing it by ignite-cassandra-store version 1.8, there is no error in any node but as previous I don't have new keyspace and table in the cassandra.

Comment: Do you check after put that keyspace does not exist?

Comment: Yes. After put and after get, I checked it

Comment: tnx Nikolay. My problem was in my code. In the xml file I set the name of cache: "cache1" and in the code I use "my_cache" name. After correction I have the problem of connection with cassandra and for that I add contactpoints property to the xml file.
`<property name="contactPoints" value="localhost"/>`